# How to have an animated background iOS

Tags: ios, animation, background

I want to place an animated background on my app. I have looked into the `UIMotionEffect` class and yes that does seem beneficial. However, what I am really looking for is something like the **dynamic wallpapers** provided in iOS settings. The way those colored circles move around is exactly what I am looking for.

I've tried this with no luck:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle"]];
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle"]];
}];
```

My only problem is I have no idea where to start. I looked into **OpenGL**. I assume it could be done that way, but it seems like a possible rabbit trail that I might not need to take. I also found some videos on YouTube but they involve **Adobe Flash**, which I do not have. Any suggestions on where to venture for this?

Comment: Did you see the session Implementing Engaging UI in iOS of WWDC 2013? There are some examples of motion effects at around 40th min of the video https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/index.php?id=226.

Comment: I checked out the video. I do like the idea of being able to have things move as the device moves, but my main goal is to have things move while the device is not moving, similar to how the dynamic background work.

Comment: So then skip the device moves part and just implement your own logic for moves and color changes...

Answer (score 1):

If it's a simple GIF you don't need to get fancy. Just separate the images (many tools to do that) and use the following code (might be some typos):

```
   NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"],
                        ........,
                        nil];
  UIImage *image = [UIImage animatedImageWithImages:array duration:6.0f];
  [image startAnimating];
```